# Unknown string format from google protocol - protobuf bad culture - Windows 8 app

Tags: c#, parsing, windows-8, app-store, cultureinfo

I m using protobuf in my app. I get from web byte array. Then I use protobuf to parse from byte array to string. This all work but after parse I get bad format of string. Example>

```
string resultString = ProtocolBuffers.StationsResponse.ParseFrom(myByteArray);
```

result in resultString is = "Bernol\303kova" but correct should be **"Bernoláková** I think problem is in culture or something like language selector. I dont know what is \303 its look like anscii chars.